# Setting text to be read column-wise by screen-reader in iText 7

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation, screen-readers, itext7

I have a page in my PDF that consists of several columns. I would like the screen-reader to read each column individually before moving on to the next column. Currently it just reads the text that appears from left to right. Is there any way to do this in iText 7?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether you create this document by yourself with iText or you want to fix this issue in already existing PDF document.

In the first case you simply need to specify that you want to create document logical structure along with document content. In order to achieve this, you need to call `PdfDocument#setTagged()` method upon creation of `PdfDocument` instance. Document logical structure is something that tools like screen readers would rely on in order to get the correct logical order of the contents.

In the second scenario, when you already have a document with several columns, however it's reading order is messed up, it is most likely that this document doesn't have proper logical structure in it (or in other words it is not *tagged* properly). The task of fixing the issue you described in already existing PDF document (this task is sometimes called *structure recognition*) is extremely difficult in general case and cannot be performed automatically as of nowadays. There are several tools that would allow you to fix such documents manually or semi-automatically (like Adobe Acrobat) but iText 7 doesn't provide structure recognition functionality right now.

Comment: It's a document that I am creating and it is already set as tagged.

Comment: @scott13 How do you create the document with several columns? Do you use `com.itextpdf.layout.ColumnDocumentRenderer` (it's a java class, however there is an analogous in .net)? There is an example of using it [on itext website](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers).